# Rcosx alpha question

Tags: trigonometry

f(x)=3−4cosx+ 3sinx

[image]

The question was to work out the maximum and smallest positive value is. I got this question wrong and I don't understand how to work out the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite $$3\sin t - 4 \cos t = 5\sin (t-b),\, b = \cos ^{-1}(3/5)$$ now, $$f(t)= 3 - 4\cos  t + 3 \sin t=3+5\sin (t-b)$$ and $f$ has a maximum value $f(\pi/2+b) = 8$ the minimum value of $f(3\pi/2 + b) = -2.$

Comment: I don't understand how 5 became sin(t-b) or the next line